# How do I add the same listener to multiple components in the NetBeans GUI Builder

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans

I am using the NetBeans GUI Builder to create a small application. To begin, let me just say that I can code everything by hand and solve this problem right away. However, I want to learn how to use the GUI Builder. This is my warning that all suggestions to not use it will get a down vote.

With that said, my current situation is that I have several `JFormattedTextField`s where I want to display an error message if the user enters data with an invalid format. The logic is the same in every case. The only difference will be to display a different error message depending on the exact formatting expected (i.e. a four digit year, a positive integer, etc.). I would like to simply write one listener that can be reused for every text field. I wrote the following method for the first text box:

```
private void formattedTextFieldFocustLost(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {
    JFormattedTextField source = (JFormattedTextField)evt.getComponent();

    if (!source.isEditValid()) {
        // TODO: Need a better error message.
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Invalid input.", "Input Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        source.requestFocusInWindow();
    }
}
```

The method signature is generated by NetBeans and is called from a generated of an anonymous inner class which extends `FocusAdapter`. Now when I go to the Design view in NetBeans and click on the combo box for the `focusLost` event of another component, this method name doesn't show up.

I also tried to create a named inner class which extends `FocusAdapter`. This doesn't show up in the event handler comboboxes, either.

What do I do to create a single method for all of my text fields?

Comment: Will post this as a comment so you can't down-vote me, but perhaps you shouldn't be using FocusListeners at all since they're pretty low level. I've always preferred using an InputVerifier for these situations.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels If you care to elaborate in an answer go ahead. I'm open to other options. I just don't want answer that say "Avoid using NetBeans GUI Builder. Code Swing apps by hand...". In the mean time, I'll do some reasearch on my own ;-)

Comment: But I would have to make that statement if I posted an answer. It's almost a reflex :). Also, I'm not really sure how to go about setting InputVerifiers in the NetBeans environment. I only know how to do it "by hand".

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Ayight. I pulled up the API docs already. I'll look into it further and see if it will fit my needs. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: After fiddling with NetBeans, I've found that it seems you can set the InputVerifier by going to the "Other Properties" list of your text component, clicking on the ... button associated with the InputVerifier property, and then add in your code, say for `new MyInputVerifier()`. You can then add in the source code a private inner class for MyInputVerifier that does your verification.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Hmmm...that would also centralize some of my other error-checking code, such as for any blank text fields...

Answer (score 3):

If you have written the handler already, say btnActionPerformed, copy the name.

In design view, right-click the component where you want to attach the handler > Properties > Events > "..." button > Add > paste existing handler name in blank field and click OK.

(Netbeans 7.3.1)

Comment: Thanks for answering this old question. I hope others will find it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own method, e.g. validate():

```
private void validate(JFormattedTextField source) {
    if (!source.isEditValid()) {
        // TODO: Need a better error message.
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Invalid input.", "Input Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        source.requestFocusInWindow();
    }
}
```

then call this method from the individual listeners that you define through the GUI Editor:

```
private void formattedTextFieldFocustLost(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {
    JFormattedTextField source = (JFormattedTextField)evt.getComponent();
    validate(source);
}
```