# When to display error messages for invalid input in Swing application

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, error-handling

I am using a `JFormattedTextField` for to format integer input for a Swing app. The default behavior for invalid input is to quietly (i.e. no error message) reset the text field to it's prior value. I want to display an error message with `JOptionPane` before returning focus to the `JFormattedTextField`.

My original solution was to implement `FocusListener`s for my text fields. I considered adding instances of the same `FocusListener` subclass to each one, but have encountered problems since I am using the NetBeans GUI Builder. [@HovercraftFullOfEels suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12117414/how-do-i-add-the-same-listener-to-multiple-components-in-the-netbeans-gui-builde) that I use an `InputVerifier`. I have implemented the following custom InputVerifier:

```
public class ValidTextFormatInputVerifier extends InputVerifier {

    @Override
    public boolean verify(JComponent jc) {
        return ((JFormattedTextField)jc).isEditValid();
    }
}
```

While looking into this further, I get the impression that `JFormattedTextField` uses `InputVerifier` internally. (I haven't found this explicitly stated anywhere yet, though.) Because of this, my custom `InputVerifier` seems superfluous.

The bigger issue is that the text field is still reset silently without any error message. I could add a call to `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog()` here. However this does not seem an appropriate place to display error messages. The `InputVerifier` does not know the exact nature of the invalid input, nor does it know the format of valid input, which is even more crucial to providing a meaningful error message.

The first solution that comes to mind is to add a constructor which takes a `String` parameter that contains the error message to display. This seems like I'm putting the error message logic in the wrong place, though.

Is there a common Java idiom for error handling and providing messages to the user? How do you suggest that I design my application to cleanly display error messages? Also, if I decide to design an interface for the software using a different platform (e.g. command-line, mobile, etc.), I want to be able to reuse as much of my existing code-base as possible. (Of course, since this is mostly a UI issue, perhaps that requirement doesn't apply as strongly as I would like here.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My first opinion is that showing a JOptionPane to the user whenever the text field focus is lost could be very annoying for users. I would display an error message when the user hits the OK button of your form. The error message could contain a list of all error messages or only the first one and focus the element with the error.

Another choice would be to use regular `JTextField` and write your own custom validators. When focus changes, your IntegerValidator (or other implementation) would validate the input string and the UI could display an error or warning icon next to the field, the same as some web applications do.

Comment: ooo...I hadn't thought of an icon next to the field. I think I'll add that as a feature in the next version.

Comment: Some frameworks also display a short error message next to the field. Not sure how it would look like in a Swing app :)

Comment: Whatever mechanism I decide to use for notifying the user of invalid input, my central question remains: What is the "best" design? I'm primarily struggling with *when* to display error messages more than *how* to display them.

Comment: See the first part of my answer for the way I would prefer to do it and how I would prefer to use an application as a user.

Comment: To clarify, by "when", I'm as much (perhaps more) concerned with which class has the responsibilty as with what user event triggers the error-handling code. (As you can probably see, I'm susceptible to over-engineering solutions.)

Comment: If you design the custom validators approach, if all the validators agree, then no message is displayed. Otherwise, display the appropriate message.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the ActionListener for the OK button will then be responsible for checking all the validators and then displaying an error message if appropriate. Is that what you are suggesting?

Comment: That's correct. This is what I suggest in the first paragraph of my answer.

Comment: I'll look into that further as a possible design. I apologize for the slow uptake and appreciate the conversation for further clarification.

Comment: I am accepting this answer because it is the most helpful in answering my most immediate concerns. @MadProgrammer has some good comments for future consideration.

Answer (score 4):

I'd have a look at [JLayer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLayer.html) (Java 7) or [JXLayer](http://java.net/projects/jxlayer/) (Java 6 & below)

This would allow you to decorate the field or form with a verity of different states.

As to when.

I'd start by using some kind of highlighter, Dan suggest using icons, which is a great idea, coupled with `JLayer`/`JXLayer` this would reduce the overall effect on the form.

I'd wait until the user tries to submit the form before displaying a dialog & forcing focus back to the invalid fields.

The basic idea would be to allow the user the freedom to move about the form without to much restriction (cause not all people think in a linear manner) but encourage them to correct any possible errors they are producing along the way without having to wait till they submit the form to find the errors (think about the worse web form you've ever used and don't do that)

Obviously, if they try and submit the form with errors, you'll want to display and error message and highlight the first offending field

For examples of `JLayer`/`JXLayer` have a look at [Validation overlays using JXLayer](http://www.pushing-pixels.org/2007/08/01/validation-overlays-using-jxlayer.html) & [How to decorate components](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/jlayer.html)

Comment: As always, you have some very insightful answers for me! This looks like some exciting stuff (and I'm developing with Java 7, too!) This looks like something I will have to add to my todo list for version 2.0.

Comment: You also touched on one thing about `InputVerifier` that has rubbed me the wrong way. I don't like the idea of forcing the user to input a correct value before ceding focus to another component.

Comment: @Code-Guru I agree.  I can't abide "fix me now" fields.  To many users simply don't think in a linear fashion. I argued this point at work and eventually won (with some concessions). Basically, you want to "guide" the user, not smack `em the head - Don't be afraid to break the rule though. Sometimes it will be necessary for a user to valid a field before been allowed to move on, these are "guide lines", "suggestions" not hard and fast, set in concert, burn in hell rules :P

Comment: Fortunately, I have complete control over this project, so the only rules are the ones I create...and I'll break them any time I see fit. (I am strongly resisting the urge for a shameless plug since this is my first Open Source project...)

Comment: @Code-Guru Look forward to hearing about it in the furture