# JButton stays pressed when focus stolen by JOptionPane

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, joptionpane, inputverifier

I am new to Swing and I have a situation. I am designing an application that renders the GUI components dynamically based on an xml file input(meta-data) . Now most of my JTextFields have InputVerifier set to them, for validation purpose. The input verifier pops up JOptionPane whenever there is an invalid input.

Now, if a user enter an invalid data and moves ahead and clicks a button on the Panel, then a dialog pops up and the user have to respond to it. but after that also the button does not paint to release state. It still looked like it is pressed but actually it is not. As the whole code is pretty messy, I am putting the problem scenario in the code below:-

What should I do so that the JButton looks unpressed? I would appreciate if the logic is also explained.

Thanks in advance.

```
package test;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import javax.swing.InputVerifier;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class VerifierTest extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public VerifierTest() {
        JTextField tf;
        tf = new JTextField("TextField1");

        getContentPane().add(tf, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        tf.setInputVerifier(new PassVerifier());

        final JButton b = new JButton("Button");
        b.setVerifyInputWhenFocusTarget(true);
        getContentPane().add(b, BorderLayout.EAST);
        b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (b.hasFocus())
                    System.out.println("Button clicked");
            }
        });

        addWindowListener(new MyWAdapter());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Frame frame = new VerifierTest();
        frame.setSize(400, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        //frame.pack();
    }

    class MyWAdapter extends WindowAdapter {

        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent event) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    class PassVerifier extends InputVerifier {

        public boolean verify(JComponent input) {
            JTextField tf = (JTextField) input;
            String pass = tf.getText();
            if (pass.equals("Manish"))
                return true;
            else {
                String message = "illegal value: " + tf.getText();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(tf.getParent(), message,
                        "Illegal Value", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, try to wrap the showMessageDialog call into a Runnable and give it to SwingUtilities::invokeLater(Runnable)

Comment: @gd14 Hi, I tried the approach you stated but it does not seem to work. The modified code is as follows:-

    
    final String message = "illegal value: " + tf.getText();
 javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message,
     "Illegal Value", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
  }
 });
 return false;

Comment: I see. What is your OS and Java version? I'm on OSX with Java 1.6 and it works just fine.

Comment: @gd1 OS - Windows 7 64 bit and Java - 1.6.27.

I have found a solution which I am detailing below, please let me know if it is a good solution. Thanks

Comment: You may want to check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12165355/when-to-display-error-messages-for-invalid-input-in-swing-application for more discussion on error handling in a Swing app.

Comment: @gd1 good idea - but doesn't help here: even with the side-effect moved into the correct verifier method (shouldYieldFocus instead of verify) - it's a bug :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method `verify` is actually not a good place to open a JOptionPane.

There are several approaches you could consider to solve your problem:

1. You want this JOptionPane to appear everytime the textfield looses the focus and the input is incorrect: use a FocusListener on the JTextField and act upon appropriate events
2. You want this JOptionPane to appear everytime the buttons is pressed: use your ActionListener to do it if the input is incorrect.

Here is a small snippet of the latter option:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.InputVerifier;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class VerifierTest extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public VerifierTest() {
        final JTextField tf = new JTextField("TextField1");

        getContentPane().add(tf, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        tf.setInputVerifier(new PassVerifier());

        final JButton b = new JButton("Button");
        b.setVerifyInputWhenFocusTarget(true);
        getContentPane().add(b, BorderLayout.EAST);
        b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (!tf.getInputVerifier().verify(tf)) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(tf.getParent(), "illegal value: " + tf.getText(), "Illegal Value",
                            JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
                if (b.hasFocus()) {
                    System.out.println("Button clicked");
                }
            }
        });
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Frame frame = new VerifierTest();
        frame.setSize(400, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    class PassVerifier extends InputVerifier {

        @Override
        public boolean verify(JComponent input) {
            final JTextField tf = (JTextField) input;
            String pass = tf.getText();
            return pass.equals("Manish");
        }
    }
}
```

Also consider setting the default close operation of the JFrame instead of adding a window listener (but it is a good approach to use a WindowListener if you want to pop up a dialog asking the user if he is sure he wants to exit your application).

Comment: Thanks I would keep that in mind and make necessary chnages. In the mean time I have found a solution which I am detailing below. Could you please confirm if that is a good solution. Thanks

Comment: Thanks this solution works perfectly. Just one more question, I would like to switch panels(dynamically determined and created) on my card layout based on the button click(called Next). In that case how should I move ahead? Thanks

Comment: @dareurdream I haven't seen your cardlayout, but the basic idea is to call next() and previous() on the CardLayout. If you want a specific component to appear, add it to the container with a String constraint and use the method show() with the String corresponding to the component you want. See more [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)

Comment: oops, mixed up the solutions: your inputVerifier always was valid :-) Nevertheless, it's not correct: the side-effect belongs into its shouldYieldFocus, not into an external handler (you don't really want to add it to all the buttons the potentially need to rely on a valid component, do you :-)

Comment: @kleopatra I am not sure I am clearly understanding what you are saying and if you refer (or not) to other comments I posted. Anyway, putting the JOptionPane effect in the shouldYieldFocus does not seem right to me: if, for example, you have a textfield with InputVerifier and an OK and Cancel button, the JOptionPane should only appear when pressing OK and not when pressing Cancel.

Comment: that's what the verifyInputWhenFocusTarget property is for: it's true by default (appropriate for the ok button) and can be set to false for a cancel button (which doesn't validate at all). The shouldYieldFocus is _designed_ to contain all the side-effects.

Answer (score 1):

I added a call to `SwingUtilities` to ensure that the GUI is on the event thread, and I removed your reference to Frame.

The GUI works for me on Windows XP.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import javax.swing.InputVerifier;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class VerifierTest implements Runnable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public VerifierTest() {

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(400, 200);

        JTextField tf;
        tf = new JTextField("TextField1");
        tf.setInputVerifier(new PassVerifier());
        frame.getContentPane().add(tf, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        final JButton b = new JButton("Button");
        b.setVerifyInputWhenFocusTarget(true);
        frame.getContentPane().add(b, BorderLayout.EAST);
        b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (b.hasFocus())
                    System.out.println("Button clicked");
            }
        });

        frame.addWindowListener(new MyWAdapter());
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new VerifierTest());
    }

    class MyWAdapter extends WindowAdapter {
        @Override
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent event) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    class PassVerifier extends InputVerifier {
        @Override
        public boolean verify(JComponent input) {
            JTextField tf = (JTextField) input;
            String pass = tf.getText();
            if (pass.equals("Manish"))
                return true;
            else {
                String message = "illegal value: " + tf.getText();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(tf.getParent(), message,
                        "Illegal Value", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The GUI is working for me too, but the real problem is with the look of the button. If we observe the console then we would find the sys out "Button Clicked" is never displayed. That means the button is never clicked. But still the button looks like it is pressed...Anyways I have found a solution and would like your opinion on that.Thanks

Comment: the implementation of InputVerifier is _invalid_

Answer (score 1):

I have added a new mouse listener to the button as below and its seems to be working fine for me now, but I am not sure if it is a good way of rectifying the buttons selection state.

```
package test;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import javax.swing.InputVerifier;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener;

public class VerifierTest extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public VerifierTest() {
        JTextField tf;
        tf = new JTextField("TextField1");

        getContentPane().add(tf, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        tf.setInputVerifier(new PassVerifier());

        final JButton b = new JButton("Button");
        b.setVerifyInputWhenFocusTarget(true);
        getContentPane().add(b, BorderLayout.EAST);
        b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (b.hasFocus())
                    System.out.println("Button clicked");
            }
        });

        b.addMouseListener(new BasicButtonListener(b) {
            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                ((JButton)e.getSource()).getModel().setArmed(false);
                ((JButton)e.getSource()).getModel().setPressed(false);
            }

        });

        addWindowListener(new MyWAdapter());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Frame frame = new VerifierTest();
        frame.setSize(400, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        // frame.pack();
    }

    class MyWAdapter extends WindowAdapter {

        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent event) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    class PassVerifier extends InputVerifier {

        public boolean verify(JComponent input) {
            JTextField tf = (JTextField) input;
            String pass = tf.getText();
            if (pass.equals("Manish"))
                return true;
            else {
                final String message = "illegal value: " + tf.getText();
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message,
                                "Illegal Value", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While this solution may work, you are actually breaking the [InputVerifier's contract](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/InputVerifier.html#verify(javax.swing.JComponent)): _This method should have no side effects_ so all it should do is verify the component input and return true or false. Moreover, you shouldn't have to "manually" modify the state of the button (unless this is really a desired effect)

Comment: @GuillaumePolet - I agree to everyword you said and I would modify my solution to the solution suggested by you above.

I would like to know your thoughts on this one too- 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12541879/design-architecture-for-a-tool

Comment: + 1 - manually sucking the button out off its weird buggy state is the only thingy that _can_ be done here, mouseListener is fine if it's working

Answer (score 1):

First: *all* implementations of InputVerifier which open the dialog in verify() are **invalid**. They violated their contract, API doc:

> This method should have no side effects.

with the "should" really meaning "must not". The correct place for side-effects is shouldYieldFocus.

Second: moving the side-effect (showing the message dialog) correctly into the shouldYieldFocus doesn't work as well ... due to a [bug (THEY call it feature request ;-)](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4533820), that's older than a decade and [in the top 10 RFEs](http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/top25_rfes.do)

Being a hack-around a bug, @dareurdrem's mouseListener is as good as any workable hack can get :-)

**Update**

After playing a bit with different options to hack around the bug, here's another hack - it's as brittle as all hacks are (and doesn't survive a LAF toggle, has to be re-installed if dynamic toggling is required)

For hacking the mouse behaviour the basic approach is to hook into the listener installed by the ui:

- find the original
- implement a custom listener which delegates most events directly to the original
- for pressed events request focus first: if yielded delegate to original, if not do nothing

The last bullet is slightly more involved because focus events can be asynchronous, so we have to invoke the check for being focused. Invoking, in turn, requires to send a release in case nobody objected.

Another quirk is the rootPane's pressed action (for its defaultButton): it's done without respecting any inputVerifiers by unconditionally calling doClick. That can be hacked by hooking into the action, following the same pattern as hooking into the mouseListener:

- find the rootPane's pressed action
- implement a custom action which checks for a potentially vetoing inputVerifier: delegate to the original if not, do nothing otherwise

The example modified along those lines:

```
public class VerifierTest implements Runnable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        InteractiveTestCase.setLAF("Win");
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(400, 200);

        JTextField tf = new JTextField("TextField1");
        tf.setInputVerifier(new PassVerifier());
        frame.add(tf, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        final JButton b = new JButton("Button");
        frame.add(b);
        b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
               System.out.println("Button clicked");
            }
        });
        // hook into the mouse listener
        replaceBasicButtonListener(b);
        frame.add(new JTextField("not validating, something else to focus"),
                BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.getRootPane().setDefaultButton(b);
        // hook into the default button action
        Action pressDefault = frame.getRootPane().getActionMap().get("press");
        frame.getRootPane().getActionMap().put("press", new DefaultButtonAction(pressDefault));
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    protected void replaceBasicButtonListener(AbstractButton b) {
        final BasicButtonListener original = getButtonListener(b);
        if (original == null) return;
        Hacker l = new Hacker(original);
        b.removeMouseListener(original);
        b.addMouseListener(l);
    }
    
    public static class Hacker implements MouseListener {
        private BasicButtonListener original;

        /**
         * @param original the listener to delegate to.
         */
        public Hacker(BasicButtonListener original) {
            this.original = original;
        }

        /**
         * Hook into the mousePressed: first request focus and
         * check its success before handling it.
         */
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(final MouseEvent e) {
            if (SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(e)) {
                if(e.getComponent().contains(e.getX(), e.getY())) {
                    // check if we can get the focus
                    e.getComponent().requestFocus();
                    invokeHandleEvent(e);
                    return;
                }
            }
            original.mousePressed(e);
        }
        
        /**
         * Handle the pressed only if we are focusOwner.
         */
        protected void handlePressed(final MouseEvent e) {
            if (!e.getComponent().hasFocus())  {
                // something vetoed the focus transfer
                // do nothing
                return;
            } else {
                original.mousePressed(e);
                // need a fake released now: the one from the
                // original cycle might never has reached us
                MouseEvent released = new MouseEvent(e.getComponent(), MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED,
                        e.getWhen(), e.getModifiers(), 
                        e.getX(), e.getY(), e.getClickCount(), e.isPopupTrigger()
                        );
                original.mouseReleased(released);
            }
        }
        

        /**
         * focus requests might be handled
         * asynchronously. So wrap the check 
         * wrap the block into an invokeLater.
         */
        protected void invokeHandleEvent(final MouseEvent e) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    handlePressed(e);
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            original.mouseClicked(e);
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            original.mouseReleased(e);
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            original.mouseEntered(e);
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            original.mouseExited(e);
        }
    }
    public static class DefaultButtonAction extends AbstractAction {
    
        private Action original;
        
        /**
         * @param original
         */
        public DefaultButtonAction(Action original) {
            this.original = original;
        }
    
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JRootPane root = (JRootPane) e.getSource();
            JButton owner = root.getDefaultButton();
            if (owner != null && owner.getVerifyInputWhenFocusTarget()) {
                Component c = KeyboardFocusManager
                        .getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager()
                         .getFocusOwner();
                if (c instanceof JComponent && ((JComponent) c).getInputVerifier() != null) {
                    if (!((JComponent) c).getInputVerifier().shouldYieldFocus((JComponent) c)) return;
                }
    
    
            }
            original.actionPerformed(e);
        }
        
    }
    /**
     * Returns the ButtonListener for the passed in Button, or null if one
     * could not be found.
     */
    private BasicButtonListener getButtonListener(AbstractButton b) {
        MouseMotionListener[] listeners = b.getMouseMotionListeners();

        if (listeners != null) {
            for (MouseMotionListener listener : listeners) {
                if (listener instanceof BasicButtonListener) {
                    return (BasicButtonListener) listener;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new VerifierTest());
    }

    
    public static class PassVerifier extends InputVerifier {
        /**
         * Decide whether or not the input is valid without
         * side-effects.
         */
        @Override
        public boolean verify(JComponent input) {
            final JTextField tf = (JTextField) input;
            String pass = tf.getText();
            if (pass.equals("Manish"))
                return true;
            return false;
        }

        /**
         * Implemented to ask the user what to do if the input isn't valid.
         * Note: not necessarily the best usability, it's mainly to
         * demonstrate the different effects on not/agreeing with
         * yielding focus transfer.
         */
        @Override
        public boolean shouldYieldFocus(final JComponent input) {
            boolean valid = super.shouldYieldFocus(input);
            if (!valid) {
                String message = "illegal value: " + ((JTextField) input).getText();
                int goAnyWay = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(input, "invalid value: " +
                        message + " - go ahead anyway?");
                valid = goAnyWay == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION;
            }
            return valid;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the real problem is in how the focus system and awt listeners interact. There are a few bugs declared in Java that the developers are going back and forth on who is responsible.
The mouse listener does : processMouseEvent and within that logic, the current FocusOwner is asked to yield Focus. it fails.  But because half the event is processed already, the button becomes armed and the focus remains with the field.

I finally saw one developer comment: Don't let the listener proceed if the field is not allowed to lose focus.

For example:
Define a JTextfield with edits to only allow values  < 100.
A message pops up when you lose focus.
I overrode my base JButton classes' processMouseEvent(MouseEvent e)
with code:

```
protected void processMouseEvent(MouseEvent e) {
    if ( e.getComponent() != null && e.getComponent().isEnabled() ) { //should not be processing mouse events if it's disabled.
            if (e.getID() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED && e.getClickCount() == 1) {
                // The mouse button is being released as per normal, and it's the first click. Process it as per normal.
                super.processMouseEvent(e);

                // If the release occured within the bounds of this component, we want to simulate a click as well
                if (this.contains(e.getX(), e.getY())) {
                    super.processMouseEvent(new MouseEvent(e.getComponent(),
                                                            MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED,
                                                            e.getWhen(),
                                                            e.getModifiers(),
                                                            e.getX(),
                                                            e.getY(),
                                                            e.getClickCount(),
                                                            e.isPopupTrigger(),
                                                            e.getButton()));
                }
            }
            else if (e.getID() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED && e.getClickCount() == 1) {
                // Normal clicks are ignored to prevent duplicate events from normal, non-moved events
            }
            else if (e.getID() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED && e.getComponent() != null && (e.getComponent().isFocusOwner() || e.getComponent().requestFocusInWindow())) {// if already focus owner process mouse event
                super.processMouseEvent(e); 
            }
            else {
                // Otherwise, just process as per normal.
                if (e.getID() != MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED) {
                    super.processMouseEvent(e); 
                }
            }
        }
}
```

in the guts of this logic is the simple questions. 
Button: Are you already focus owner.
if not: can you(Button) possibly GAIN focus ( remember - shouldYieldFocus() is called on the current focus holder inside the requestFocusInWindow() call and will return false ALWAYS if not valid )

This Also has the side affect of popping up your error dialog!

This logic Stops the Java libraries processMouseEvent logic from processing half an event while the Focus System stops it from completing.

Obviously you'll need this type of logic on all your different JComponents that perform an action on a click.