# How to make sure user enters a valid number in java GUI

Tags: java, user-interface, user-input

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When to display error messages for invalid input in Swing application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12165355/when-to-display-error-messages-for-invalid-input-in-swing-application)

i need to create a java GUI that prompts the user to enter numbers in various textboxes totalling 100. but my question is  how do i force the user to enter a total of 100 without coming up with annoying pop-up boxes?

Comment: Sorry, but Java doesn't come with any way to validate data. That just wasn't in the language specification.

Comment: Check out the question that I linked above. Hopefully it has some helpful information for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a label above each textbox that is invisible, and make them visible if they werent filled in.

Answer (score 0):

You can display a status message in say a simple `JLabel`, and perhaps disable any associated buttons. Add a `DocumentListener` to each of the text field documents to recalculate the status every time an edit is made. (Assuming Swing - other windowing toolkits are available.)